# Positng From PHP To Java Broken Characters

Tags: java, php, character-encoding

I'm running a PHP file on the XAMPP server and posting a form to my Apache Tomcat Java Web server. When I debug the Java project, I can see that some Turkish characters are broken.

My PHP file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RESULT</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body onload="javascript:moveWindow()">
    <form name="pay_form" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/">
        <?php
        $postParams = array();
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            array_push($postParams, $key);
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" .$key ."\" value=\"" .$value."\" /><br />";
        }   

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function moveWindow() {
                document.pay_form.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sendig the name as "ilkay günel". But in Java request object that is "ilkay gÃ¼nel". The "ü" character is broken. Broken character is like this one. Other Turkish characters are broken like ü.

Does anybody have an idea why Turkish characters are broken in Java request object?

Comment: Define "broken". There is nothing wrong in your form. For all we know it's maybe just your debugger showing them wrongly while they're actually fine in your application.

Comment: my guess: the Java side is not expecting unicode character set?

Comment: I'm sendig the name as "ilkay günel".
But in Java request that is "ilkay gÃ¼nel". The "ü" character is broken. Broken character is like this one.

Comment: So the name is sent in `UTF-8` but it's being interpreted as something else (such as `ISO-8859-1`). Has Tomcat been configured to use something else than `UTF-8`?